# What is a good recipe for high quality coffee beans that are no longer fresh?

Tags: beans, whole-bean, recycling, food

I have a subscription to a roaster who mails me a 250g bag of freshly-roasted, single origin coffee beans every week. To my taste, the beans are best within the first 20 days after roasting after which the aroma declines pretty quickly.

Sometimes, when I travel for instance, I end up with bags that I wasn't able to use by the time a fresher bag arrives. The older beans are not bad by any stretch-- in fact they are still far better than 99% of the beans that are sold in supermarkets which are generally a year old-- but I'd always rather use the fresher beans to make coffee if I have the choice.

Are there any good recipes or preparations that could put these once-fresh beans to good use?

Comment: Would you consider other storage methods that might extend freshness (such as these questions on storing [whole bean](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/1/262), or [ground](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/12/262), or [freezing](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/99/262), or even [freezing already-brewed coffee](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/1633/262))? See more tagged [tag:storage]. Or [bake some in a chocolate cake](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/23352/25286)! There's plenty of space for more answers on this!

Comment: Buy yourself a vacuum sealer. They are easy to use and excellent money-savers as they preserve food for much longer periods. I recently vacuum sealed 1kg coffee into 100g packs. They can then also be frozen to preserve them even longer.

Comment: I think you're suggesting proactive preservation rather than salvaging stale beans. Vacuum-packing beans isn't generally a good idea, especially for freshly-roasted beans. [Another question of yours](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/1914/262) has more information and answers on vaccum and freezing.

Answer (score 3):

One option is a somewhat obscure preparation method, but one that works best with older-ish beans: Nel drip (nel pot) preparation recommends beans that are a few weeks old; here's [a Nel preparation guide from Blue Bottle](https://bluebottlecoffee.com/preparation-guides/nel-drip). I don't know why older beans are recommended, except perhaps tradition.

See also other questions tagged [nel-drip](/questions/tagged/nel-drip) including [another question of mine on Nel](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/434/how-does-nel-drip-compare-to-paper-filtered-pour-over).

Answer (score 3):

Another option to quickly use coffee is [cold-brew](/questions/tagged/cold-brew) since it requires large amounts of coffee to produce a small amount of concentrate that lasts up to a week refrigerated.

I personally use this method to "finish" an older roast so that I can start using a fresher one for my other brewing methods.

[Stumptown recommendation:](https://www.stumptowncoffee.com/brew-guides/filtron)

```
12 oz coffee + 56 oz H2O for 16 hours
```

[Blue Bottle recommendation:](https://bluebottlecoffee.com/preparation-guides/cold-brew)

```
16 oz coffee + 2 liters H2O for 12 hours
```

[Serious Eats recommendation:](http://drinks.seriouseats.com/2010/07/how-to-make-cold-brew-ice-coffee-summer.html)

```
8 oz coffee + 36 oz H2O for 12 hours
```